# Tab Bar Button color in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, swift3

In Swift 2 I used a User Defined Runtime Attribute in Storyboard with a key path of tintColor to change the tab bar item icon colors. However, it looks like tintColor was removed with Swift 3. How can I change the selected color of the tab bar items in a tab bar controller in Swift 3?

Thanks!

EDIT: Attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: Tried it in Xcode 8 swift 3, works fine. Are you setting the tint color for the tab bar itself or on one of the bar items?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm trying to set the color of the individual items. I just attached a screenshot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes` to change text color of individual bar items.
Put this in `viewDidLoad` method of each tab:

```
self.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red()], for:.selected)
```

---

To change the icon and text tint color together a simple solution is to change the tabBar tint color in viewWillAppear method of each tab:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.red()
}
```

---

Another solution to change the image tint color is to create an extension for UIImage and use it to change the selected image with custom tint:

```
extension UIImage {
    func tabBarImageWithCustomTint(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        context.translate(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
        context.scale(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

        context.clipToMask(rect, mask: self.cgImage!)

        tintColor.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)

        var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        newImage = newImage.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Use this code to change the selected image:

```
self.tabBarItem.selectedImage = self.tabBarItem.selectedImage?.tabBarImageWithCustomTint(tintColor: UIColor.red())
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I want to change the color of the icon. I already figured out how to change the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The latest code as par Swift 3 is

```
extension UIImage {

    func tabBarImageWithCustomTint(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

        context.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)

        tintColor.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)

        var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        newImage = newImage.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        return newImage
    }
}
```